# Path to Run WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have difficulty to Run the API with Browser or PostMan. The problem is the path so I get 404 error.

This is the path:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Also WebAPIConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "v{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthHandler());
}
```

This is the controller method I need to Run:

```
public class BankViewerController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<BuilderList> GetBuilderList()
    {
        //......
    }
}
```

The path I try is:

```
http://localhost:62815/BankViewerController/GetBuilderList
```

It even does not get to the first line of the method and it gave me 404 error so I am pretty sure it is Path.

Comment: Clearly your route definition includes a version number and your URL does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given route template:

```
routeTemplate: "v{version}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

You called the wrong URL that did not match the template

```
http://localhost:62815/BankViewerController/GetBuilderList
```

You will need something like

```
http://localhost:62815/v1/BankViewer/GetBuilderList
```

Exclude `Controller` from the controller name when calling the URL. it is a convention.